# silverlight application only works in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I inherited an ASP.Net 4.0 application that contains a Silverlight component. The person who programmed it originally is long gone and everyone else here is as clueless as I am when it comes to Silverlight.

I've recently made changes to the .Net portion that has nothing to do with the Silverlight portion. After publishing, the Silverlight portion only works in IE11, and in every other version of IE (and FireFox and Chrome) I get a client error of:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application An exception occurred during the 
operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.   
  at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()\n   
  at _10v5.ServiceReference1.CheckImageCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()\n   
  at _10v5.MainPage.proxy_CheckImageCompleted(Object sender, CheckImageCompletedEventArgs e)\n   
  at _10v5.ServiceReference1.eefimageserviceClient.OnCheckImageCompleted(Object state)
```

This to me seems to be an issue with the code itself and in turn should not work in ANY browser. So why does IE 11 work?

**EDIT** This is a windows 7 machine

Comment: maybe this can help http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/silverlight-does-not-work-in-ie-11-windows-81-app/8665ccb8-51ba-47e3-988c-5954095151c3

Comment: Well the exception says to check the inner exception....did you check it?

Comment: Looks like an exception from a failed image load, could be that IE is reading from cache. Try running fiddler and see what requests are failing.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I ended up leaving it alone for a couple days, tried it again and everything was working fine. System admin said nothing changed on the server end and since nothing changed on my end I can only assume that it was the work of a magical troll.